# Beginner issues with shell scripting

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I'm pretty new to the scene so I came across a few problems when I used vi

1. I can't figure out how to apply commands to it. I was supposed to look for the string "happy" in a file, which I could do outside the script with `grep -i happy test.txt | wc -l` but I don't know how to make the script scan the file.
2. Printing to screen is another problem, I tried simply print or echo but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with syntax.
3. What's the proper way to execute the script? I tried test.txt script1 but that obviously didn't work.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Try a tutorial like [this](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/bash-tute.html) to get the hang of bash (eg variables, if statements, using commands). Then to run a script, cd to its directory and try `./myscript.sh` to run a script called `myscript.sh`.

Comment: look for "bash guide" here -> http://www.tldp.org/guides.html

Comment: `vi` isn't really designed to be used in scripts, it's an interactive editor. For scripting you usually use `sed` or `ed`.